# Creating LWC OSS app using Lightning Web Runtime

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-oss, lightning-web-runtime

Salesforce is deprecating create-lwc-app. Instead, Salesforce is suggesting to create an LWC OSS app using Lighting Web Runtime.

The command to create the LWC OSS app is `npm init lwr`

I ran `npm init lwr` command successfully by selecting the following command-line options.

[image]

The output of this command is shown on the below screen.

[image]

Then I am changing the directory and going into lwr-project. Then I am running the command `npm install`.

After running the `npm install` command I am getting the following error.
[image]

I have installed Git on my laptop and it is working fine. Please see the below screenshot.
[image]

**Can somebody help me resolve the issue so that I can create the LWC OSS app?**

Comment: is the file path in the error where you have your git.exe file?

Comment: @glls, Yes this is the file path error. 1711 error enoent Error while executing:
1711 error enoent C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.EXE ls-remote -h -t https://github.com/octref/vscode-textmate.git
1711 error enoent
1711 error enoent
1711 error enoent spawn git ENOENT
1712 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
1713 verbose exit [ -4058, true ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override the vscode-textmate package with 6.0.0. There are few solutions to this, I like using `yarn` and adding the following resolution to your package:

```
resolutions: {
  "vscode-textmate": "6.0.0"
}
```

Then run `yarn install`. This will replace npm for the package and it is advised to remove package.lock-file as yarn uses yarn.lock.

If you need npm for reasons, there is a package called [NPM force Resolutions](https://github.com/rogeriochaves/npm-force-resolutions). Add the above resolutions parameter and the following to your preinstall script: `npx npm-force-resolutions`.

#### Reason

The reason this is happening is because `@lwrjs/markdown-view-provider` is requiring the package `shiki@npm:0.9.15`. Salesforce needs to move to shiki@npm:^0.10 to resolve this. We are not doing a resolution for shiki to 0.10 to minimize issues. LWR uses shiki for its markdown renderer.